# Fading DIV depending on its character count

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I am completely new to jQuery and trying to build a very simple content slider that fades between some DIVs. The duration of each transition/fade should depend on the number of characters within the individual DIV.

My current code appears to count the characters and adjust the setTimeout function, yet it does so for the next div, not the one counted upon.

Any help would be very appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var allBoxes = $("div.boxes").children("div");
  transitionBox(null, allBoxes.first());
});

function transitionBox(from, to) {
  function next() {
    var nextTo;
    // here i am getting the length of the div
    var dur = $(this).text().length * 10;
    if (to.is(":last-child")) {
      nextTo = to.closest(".boxes").children("div").first();
    } else {
      nextTo = to.next();
    }
    to.fadeIn(500, function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        transitionBox(to, nextTo);
        // adding the length here delays the next slide, not the one i counted the characters in
      }, dur);
    });
  }

  if (from) {
    from.fadeOut(500, next);
  } else {
    next();
  }
}
```

```css
.boxes div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box1">text1</div>
  <div class="box2">text2</div>
  <div class="box3">text3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the following line:

```
var dur = $(this).text().length * 10;
```

You can't use `$(this)` here, instead use the `to` variable, because `this` is a `window` object in your case. Here's a good article about `this` in JavaScript http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/

Comment: wow! thanks a ton, paul! (would have never imagined that i was actually that close :))